# Adding pem certificate to project

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have a project, where I make a request to a server (https). The server has only a self-signed certificate, so I get an error: 'The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be ...'. The problem is, that I have no access to the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, because it is in a framework (I cannot even see the header of the class that implements the protocol). 
I have the pem certificate of the server. Is there a way to add it somehow to my project, and the server to be considered safe? For now, I need it to work only in simulator, so if I could add it only to the simulator, that would also be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Better you start to check out the MKNetworkKit. As far as I know support pem. It is released under attribution license, or you can pay it. Here is the link [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm not allowed to use any other framework (customer requirement). I'm stuck with the ones already in the project.

Comment: Well if you .pay it, you pass the attribution requirements, unfortunately what you want to do is not easy. Probably is better to ask a DST on Apple, I know that one of thei engineer (Quin) has the answer, I remember that there was a similar discussion on Apple dev forum and he said if you want a solution open a DST.